# RestSharp Serializer Setter has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net, restsharp

I am struggling to make RestSharp talk with MVC API with EF4 and I'm very close to making it work. In order to overcome the interface limitation of the stock serializer I am using the Json.NET serializer. For the deserialization it worked out of the box but I can't make RestSharp use my custom serializer. The method `Serialize`is not getting called. Everything compiled great but doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
var client = CreateClient();
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
var request = new RestRequest("api/{type}s", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("type", typeof(T).Name);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("criteria", criteria);
IRestResponse<List<T>> response = client.Execute<List<T>>(request);
HandleResponse(response);
return response.Data;
```

Any ideas?

*Edit*

I tried to follow an example and change the post method to accept `JObject` and it worked!. But trying to call `jitem.ToObject<Item>()` caused the following exception:

```
Error converting value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataAbstractionLayer.Poco.ItemCheckpoint]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[DataAbstractionLayer.Poco.ItemCheckpoint]'.
```

But more interesting is the inner exception:

```
Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[DataAbstractionLayer.Poco.ItemCheckpoint].
```

Could it be that Json.NET converts collection items automatically to string?